# how to get value from other script? (in html)

Tags: javascript, html, node.js, highcharts

I want to get value from other script.

(about socket.io) A script -> (about highchart) **B script**

this is **A script**

```
<script>
var socket = io();

socket.on('currTemp', function(data){
    document.getElementById("temp").innerHTML = "Temperature : " + data;
                   ***// I WANT 'data'.***
}); </script>
```

and this is **B script**

```
<script type="text/javascript"> 

....
code
....

setInterval(function () {
var point,
    newVal,
    inc;

if (chartRpm) {
    point = chartRpm.series[0].points[0];
    inc = ------> ***I want 'inc = data '***
    newVal = inc;

    if (newVal < 0 || newVal > 1200) {
        newVal = point.y - inc;
    }

    point.update(newVal);
}}, 2000); </script>
```

this code is in same file. how to do that ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can assign a global variable in one script like this:

```
window.myVariable = "some_value";
```

and then access it like you would any other variable in your other script;

Answer (score 0):

Declare a var globally simply with `var data;`
Both scripts should be able to access the variable.

Do check out https://www.w3schools.com/js/js_scope.asp.

Answer (score 0):

You options are:

1- Global Variable: By Assigning ***window.data = data*** in A script and use it in B script by using ***inc = window.data***

2- Use global events where A script fires an event with data attached to it and it will caught by B script.

3- Use any JS state management lib to share data between "components"